# Size problems with ImageView in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have the following problem. When I get image from drawable folders I get the image with correct sizes and when I move the same picture to assets folder and retrieve it from there it appears to be very small. It's not a problem in the resolution of the device, it's something else. But I can't find what's wrong with loading images from assets, why it makes them so small?

Comment: Try posting your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put your graphics into the proper drawable folders, Android scales the pictures to match different screen densities.
When you take a picture out of the assets folder, the picture is taken **as is**.
No scaling occurs.
And, depending on the **resolution in dpi** of your image and that of your device, the image can look bigger or smaller.

This is also why you should always provide images in different resolutions (you probably know that you'd put your 160 dpi images in the drawable-mdpi folder, your 320 dpi images in your drawable-xhdpi folder, ...)

So, no wonder, if the images taken out of a different folder don't fit well on every device.

Answer (score 0):

As based on drawable folders which device  choose. If you use common drawable folder, device will pick desired size of image which is equal to what you are using in assets. Instead if you copy and paste in hdpi or ldpi drawable, device will choose image based on desired device size.
See this.

> http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html